# Node js - Loading Loop

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have a node JS which works fine on Local Environment, i tried to run it on my server with forever. When i go to the url it just keeps loading and nothing is displayed. I get no response the page just goes into a long loading loop

```
var path = require('path');
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var app = express();

app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 8080);
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.get('*', function(req, res) {
  res.redirect('/#' + req.originalUrl);
});

app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  console.error(err.stack);
  res.send(500, { message: err.message });
});

app.listen(app.get('port'), function() {
  console.log('Express server listening on port ' + app.get('port'));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your application runs into an infinite redirect loop because all requests are handled by the `*` endpoint wich always redirects.

Possibly you want to add some kind of condition in `*` endpoint.

Comment: thanks, i tried  res.sendfile('./public/index.html'); instead and i'm getting on the web browser that the pahe takes too much time to load. Any idea ?

Comment: @CREAZPRO as I said it's the redirect loop, browser opens a page, receive redirect HTTP code and makes another HTTP-request, receive redirect HTTP code again and so on...

Comment: I understood thanks but how can i fix it ? My index.html is in the public folder. =)

Comment: It's actually not because of that if i disable my firewall for testing the site works fine... Any idea ? It looks like it's a PORT issue.

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved my issue by opening the 8080 PORT in the firewall via VHM.